# fade in and out for div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 div tag.If i click div with class adm, emp div want to get blur.After I clicked emp div It back to its own state and adm div will get blur.Now blured div doesn't back to its original state.

I attached html and jquery code.

```
jquery
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".adm").click(function(){
  $(".emp").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
   if($(".adm").fadeTo(0.15))
    $(".adm").fadeIn();
  });
$(".emp").click(function(){
$(".adm").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
 if($(".emp").fadeTo(0.15))
  $(".emp").fadeIn();
 });
});
```

```
 html 
 <div class="adm">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="emp">
  ...
 </div>
```

[image]

[image]

If I click employer employee will blur. after I clicked employee It doesn't back to its original state.now It should appear as third image[image]

Comment: can you please write your code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `fadeTo()` calls in `if` statements? That function does not return a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".adm").click(function(){
  $(".emp").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
   $(".adm").fadeTo("slow",1);
  });
$(".emp").click(function(){
$(".adm").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
$(".emp").fadeTo("slow",1);
 });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xgomyb1t/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use use fadeTo method to change the transparency of the current element.

Modified **jQuery Code**

```
$(".adm").click(function(){
    $(".emp").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
    $(".adm").fadeTo("slow",1);
});

$(".emp").click(function(){
    $(".adm").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
    $(".emp").fadeTo("slow",1);
});
```

**jsFiddle link**- http://jsfiddle.net/6ynwnzgr/

Answer (score 1):

use this, you don't need `if` statements

```
$(".adm").click(function(){
   $(".emp").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
   $(".adm").fadeTo("slow",1);
  });

$(".emp").click(function(){
 $(".adm").fadeTo("slow",0.15);
 $(".emp").fadeTo("slow",1);
 });
```

**working demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/243qgkn1/1/